# Looking for a specific character with hasNext() Java

Tags: java, regex

I need to find whether the next item that a scanner will see will be character '*'.

Is there a way to use something like Scanner.hasNext('*') to find out if the next item is indeed a star?

Comment: You could set the delimiter of a Scanner to a single character. Then, `next().equals("*")`

Comment: Scanner has a `hasNext(Pattern pattern)` method, so you can use regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scanner` supports `Pattern` so you can use regex to your advantage and check if the next item is indeed `*` like this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean hasNextStar = scanner.hasNext(Pattern.compile("\\*"));
```

Since `*` is a special token in regex you have to escape it with `\\`